# Discord.py bot won't join voice

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot. It works fine for responding to certain messages, which is part of what I wanted it to do. I now want it to be able to join the voice channel, but it wont:

```
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get


TOKEN = 'token string here
BOT_PREFIX = '/'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

players = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name + ' is now online.\n')
```

and then after my message handling @bot.event,

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    print('Join executed')
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    print (f"The bot has joined {channel}\n")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        print(f"The bot has left {channel}")
    else:
        print("Bot was asked to leave, but was not in one.")
```

I'm very new, so it could be (or probably is) a very simple, stupid fix.

The join command isn't even being processed, as that print statement isn't showing up in console when I call it in the discord chat.

I was following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bp9SZYqIWIM&ab_channel=HowToDoThings) to a T, and his clearly works fine.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you calling `/join` in a text channel the bot can see?
Do other commands work besides `/join`? (Try making a simple command that just prints to console)

Comment: Do you have an `on_message()` event?

Comment: I do have an on_message event, and it works perfectly fine. Allister, I will try some other simple commands and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got on_message event. If you do, check this [docs page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).
Also i have no idea why you passed `pass_context` they removed it at version 1.0, and it doesn't even exist now.

Answer (score 0):

Check below. This will work with the latest version of discord.py.

```
   @bot.command(name='join', invoke_without_subcommand=True)
    async def join(ctx):
       destination = ctx.author.voice.channel
       if ctx.voice_state.voice:
         await ctx.voice_state.voice.move_to(destination)
         return
    
       ctx.voice_state.voice = await destination.connect()
       await ctx.send(f"Joined {ctx.author.voice.channel} Voice Channel")
```